# wdk 8.1 kmdf driver blue screen

Tags: c, windows-7, visual-studio-2015, driver, wdk

I am facing an annoying error while starting a kernelmode driver. Currently I am using a service to start the driver "on demand". The driver gets loaded but immediately fails with a bluescreen.

The code of the driver is very simple:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    DbgPrint("DriverEntry\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am fairly new to driver/kernel developement and thus I am just trying to do very small steps. Nevertheless I am not sure what information is relevant in order to enable somebody to give me the right hint.

Also I don't know how to interpret the data of the bluescreen. Can I find the displayed addresses in somekind of dumpfile that leads me to the error's source?

Is there a general "checklist" to avoid the most obvious errors that can occur during driver developement? Because I feel like the bug is not inside the driver's code.

I am currently using WDK 8.1 with MS Visual Studio 2015 Community on MS Windows 7 SP1 (64 Bit).

To be able to run the driver for test scenarios on my local machine, I disabled the driver signature enforcement some dozen times. Maybe that's some relevant information.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: which STOP code do you get? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The stopcode is 0x7E, which means "SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED". The exception code is 0xFFFFFFFF80000003, which seems to relate to the code 0x80000003 from the msdn documentation and is described as "STATUS_BREAKPOINT".

Comment: check the DbgPrint doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543632(v=vs.85).aspx. Also have you compiled the driver for Win7? My last driver was for NT4, so I don't know any newer stuff. Wait for someone who has more knoweledge

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my day :) I tried a lot of stuff in order to solve the problem and i also set up a completely new driver project.. however, i forgot to reset the Target OS Version to the correct value, in my case it was Windows 7. **Solution: Project -> Properties -> Driver Settings -> General -> Target OS Version "Windows <version>"**

Comment: ok, post your steps for retargeting as answer and mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The driver was built for a wrong OS-version. These are the steps necassary for retargeting a kernel mode driver in MS Visual Studio 2015 using WDK 8.1:

Go to the titlebar and select ...

**Solution: Project -> Properties -> Driver Settings -> General -> Target OS Version**

You can now choose the correct OS-version from a drop-down list.